# Saving solidworks drawings as PDF file with prefix

Tags: vb.net, solidworks

I'm trying to save a solidworks drawing file using macros and adding a prefix to the PDF. The code works with adding everything after the it pulls the name of the file from solidworks, but it can't seem to add the prefix

CODE:

```
Dim swApp As Object
Sub main()
Dim swApp As SldWorks.SldWorks
Dim swModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Dim swExportPDFData As SldWorks.ExportPdfData
Dim strFilename As String
Dim status As Boolean
Dim errors As Long, warnings As Long
Dim prefix As String
Dim CurrRev As String
Dim strFilenameShort As String
Dim TempString As String




Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set swModel = swApp.ActiveDoc

'Save
status = swModel.Save3(swSaveAsOptions_e.swSaveAsOptions_Silent, errors, warnings)

'Export to PDF if it is a drawing
If (swModel.GetType = swDocDRAWING) Then

prefix = (InputBox("Enter Company Prefix"))
CurrRev = (InputBox("Enter Current Revision"))

strFilenameShort = swModel.GetPathName
strFilenameShort = Left(strFilenameShort, Len(strFilenameShort) - 7)
TempString = CStr(strFilenameShort)
strFilename = prefix & TempString & "REV" & CurrRev & ".PDF"


Set swExportPDFData = swApp.GetExportFileData(1)
swModel.Extension.SaveAs strFilename, 0, 0, swExportPDFData, 0, 0


End If
Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
End Sub
```

Comment: what happens when you run, do you get an error, did you debug to see what happens when you try SaveAs. welcome to SOF :D

Comment: the Save as PDF does work, but it only saves the file name without the prefix

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Hello Siddiq Khareghat,

in your example you are combining the **prefix** with the full path of **TempString** which is wrong because the result would be something like "**prefixC:\...REV1.pdf**"

Here is an example with multiple steps which extract the needed parts of the model pathname. At the end everything is combined with the **prefix** and **CurrRev**

```
' PathName of current model document
Dim sModelFullPath As String
sModelFullPath = swModel.GetPathName

' get path name without filename
Dim sFilePath As String
sFilePath = Left(sModelFullPath, InStrRev(sModelFullPath, "\"))

' get filename and extension
Dim sFileName As String
sFileName = Right(sModelFullPath, Len(sModelFullPath) - InStrRev(sModelFullPath, "\"))

' get filename without extension
Dim sFileNameWithoutExtension As String
sFileNameWithoutExtension = Left(sFileName, InStrRev(sFileName, ".") - 1)

' combine everything to new path name
Dim sNewFullPath As String
sNewFullPath = prefix & sFileNameWithoutExtension & "REV" & CurrRev & ".pdf"

' SaveAs with new full path
Set swExportPDFData = swApp.GetExportFileData(1)
swModel.Extension.SaveAs sNewFullPath, 0, 0, swExportPDFData, 0, 0
```

Comment: Thank you very much, that seems to do the job